# Can't explain difference between two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MONTH(T0.DocDate) AS 'Months', 
    SUM(isnull(T1.InvQty,0)) - SUM(isnull(T2.InvQty,0)) AS 'Normal Scrap Tons', 
    SUM(round(T1.LineTotal * (100 - isnull(T0.DiscPrcnt,0)) / 100,2)) - SUM(isnull(T2.LineTotal,0)) AS 'Normal Scrap Purchase Value'
FROM 
    OPCH T0 
INNER JOIN 
    PCH1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    RPC1 T2 ON T0.DocNum = T2.BaseRef 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ORPC T3 ON T2.DocEntry = T3.DocEntry 
WHERE 
    T1.ItemCode IN ('Scrap-02') 
    AND YEAR(T0.DocDate) = YEAR('2015-09-15')
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(T0.DocDate)
```

This returns:

[image]

However when I run the below query, specifying Month 9 (September),

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MONTH(T0.DocDate) AS 'Months', 
    SUM(isnull(T1.InvQty,0)) - SUM(isnull(T2.InvQty,0)) AS 'Normal Scrap Tons', 
    SUM(round(T1.LineTotal * (100 - isnull(T0.DiscPrcnt,0)) / 100,2)) - SUM(isnull(T2.LineTotal,0)) AS 'Normal Scrap Purchase Value'
FROM 
    OPCH T0  
INNER JOIN 
    PCH1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    RPC1 T2 ON T0.DocNum = T2.BaseRef 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ORPC T3 ON T2.DocEntry = T3.DocEntry 
WHERE 
    T1.ItemCode IN ('Scrap-02') 
    AND T0.DocDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-09-15'
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(T0.DocDate)
```

I get the following result:

[image]

Checking for all other completed months, i.e adding: T0.DocDate BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31', the result does not show any difference from the above top query for the month of August.

Why do I get the difference on the incomplete month of Sept (database I,m using was backed up in mid Sept)

Comment: September has 30 days, not 15.

Comment: Maybe next time try to point direct where is the problem.... Have to read 3 time to see you have different value for september.

Comment: Why use `between` to filter to one month? Why not be simple and use `month` or `datepart`? I mean you did use this for the `select` clause, so I'm not sure why you do something different (and too short) in the `where`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `docDate` has no time component, then try putting in the last day of September:

```
WHERE T1.ItemCode IN ('Scrap-02') AND
      T0.DocDate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-09-30'
```

If you don't like worrying about time components, then use:

```
WHERE T1.ItemCode IN ('Scrap-02') AND
      T0.DocDate >= '2015-09-01' AND T0.DocDate < '2015-10-01'
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I will point to this part on your question

> Why do I get the difference on the incomplete month of Sept (database I'm using was backed up in mid Sept)

If you only have half september both query should be equal. So my guess is you have some data after `2015-09-15`

So do a query to validate

```
SELECT *
FROM OPCH T0
WHERE T0.DocDate > `2015-09-15`
```

Comment: Yes, there is data after the 15th of Sept, in the top query, YEAR('2015-09-15') the date will be a parameter in a report. Guess my question is to set it such that for if a user enters "2015-09-15", the data fetches Sept data only upto 15th. But already solved.

Comment: So as I say the difference is query 1 use every day on september but query 2 only first 15. I think you assume backup will only have data until 15. If this solve your question remember accept it as the correct answer.